# LLVM check function result

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to LLVM IR. Wondering how can I check the result of a method call? I'm trying to use an online compiler https://godbolt.org/

I write below code that want to do something like below.

```
if (a > b) {
    return a + 20;
} else {
    return a + b;
}
```

Am I writing it correct? How can I verify the value that is return by method call?

```
define i32 @ssa2() {
entry:
    %a = alloca i32;
    %b = alloca i32;
    store i32 3, i32* %a;
    store i32 5, i32* %b;
    %va = load i32, i32* %a;
    %vb = load i32, i32* %b;
    %cond = icmp ugt i32 %va, %vb;
    br i1 %cond, label %IfGreater, label %IfNotGreater;
IfGreater:
    %add1 = add nsw i32 %va, 20;
    ret i32 %add1;
IfNotGreater:
    %add2 = add nsw i32 %va, %vb;
    ret i32 %add2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check or verify what? That it is an integer? Or do you want to write a unit test and are wondering how do to that?

Comment: @arnt yeah, like check the value that the ssa2 method returns. In Java I can just print it out, but not sure how to do that in LLVM IR

Comment: Well, if you look for a method called check() you won't find it, but if you look for methods called [print()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a1e56c814d11206720cc23059b871128d) or [dump()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#af7dca9a9e816ef69fd9e9467f64f72b4) you'll have more luck. This shows, I think, only that using the right verb helps you find what you want.

Comment: Those methods run at compile-time. If you want to check the runtime result, you might need to e.g. call the C function `printf`. Maybe `lli` would be another option.